# Pulse generator with single op amp and diode

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, circuit-design, pulse, duty-cycle

I want to design pulse generator with specific period and duty cycle. I found a pulse generator with single op amp and diode. I couldn't find information about how to calculate period and duty cycle. If you have any suggestion about pulse generator design with single op amp (not comparator or 555 timer). You can find my schematic in figure below.

[image]

Comment: It's a relaxation oscillator... solve threshold voltages of opamp comparator with hysteresis,  then rc charge/discharge time

Comment: Find a better design. That one has the +5 V input connected to a -5 V supply so it won't work. The layout is poor (ground symbols rotated 90° and 180°) so I wouldn't waste any time on it.

Comment: İ obtained pulse with this schematic and why  did rotating the ground make my layout poor?

Comment: The rotated ground symbols made it look amateur. (I didn't realise you had drawn it.) They should point downwards (to the ground). See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjD2EM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The basic relaxation oscillator.*

How it works:

- OUT is initially low, C1 is discharging and the threshold voltage, Vt, is at 1/3 supply. (R1 and R2 form a half-supply voltage divider but R3 is in parallel with R2 pulling it down to V1/3.)
- When Vc drops below V1/3 the op-amp output switches high, Vt changes to 2/3 V1 and C1 starts charging.
- The half-cycle time could be roughly approximated by \$ \tau = R4 \cdot C1 = 10k \cdot 1µ = 10 \ \mathrm{ms} \$ if the capacitor was charging from 0 to 63%. As it is actually charging from 33% to 66% the time will be somewhat shorter - about 7 ms on the simulation below.

[image]

*Figure 2. The waveforms obtained from Figure 1.*

The simplest way to control the duty cycle is to control the charge and discharge times independently with diodes as shown in Figure 3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmFNrw.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Duty-cycle control with diodes.*

[image]

*Figure 4. Resultant simulation.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRSN7G.png)</sup>

*Figure 5. By adding a potentiometer the duty cycle can be adjusted while maintaining the frequency reasonably stable.*

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI1HYA.png)</sup>

*Figure 6. You can also leave out one of the diodes. In this case discharging C1 is done through R5 only while charging is done through R5 and R4.*

---

There's a useful calculator at [Must Calculate](http://mustcalculate.com/electronics/capacitorchargeanddischarge.php?vfrom=1&vto=2&vs=3&c=1u&r=10k) that will work out the time constants for you. For the timing of my Figure 1 it worked out 6.93 ms.

You can play with the CircuitLab simulations by "editing" my question and editing the schematic. Just don't save them on your way out!

Note that I haven't included the voltage drop of the diodes in my calculations. It will affect the results a bit but the simulator should pick that up for you.